# Julia: How do I get all the points on my scatter plot to be the same RGBA color?

Tags: julia

I am trying to create a simple scatter plot where all the points are colored in electric indigo:

```
# AbsVMinus and AbsV are x and y respectively
scatter(AbsVMinusI, AbsV, title = "Color-magnitude diagram", seriescolor = RGBA(140, 20, 252, 1), legend = false)
```

I wrote this line by using the Colors documentation section as an example. However,I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: (140, 20, 252, 1) are integers in the range 0-255, but integer inputs are encoded with the N0f8
  type, an 8-bit type representing 256 discrete values between 0 and 1.
  Consider dividing your input values by 255, for example: RGBA{N0f8}(140/255,20/255,252/255,1/255)
  Or use `reinterpret(N0f8, x)` if `x` is a `UInt8`.
  See the READMEs for FixedPointNumbers and ColorTypes for more information.
```

I tried the error suggestion, but I get the following:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: N0f8 not defined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `using FixedPointNumbers` will give you `N0f8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All arguments are on scale zero to one.

To see your purple color just do:

```
RGBA(140/255, 20/255, 252/255, 1.0)
```